# Cakephp images from css using themes

Tags: cakephp, plugins, themes, assets

im using themes in an app im doing, and need a global css/img/js folder

i have tried using app/webroot as this folder, but cant get any css from a theme to show the images.

I have a setup like :: `/app/views/themed/my_theme/webroot/css/file.css`

With some css that looks like:

```
...
body{
     background-image: url('../img/file.jpg');
}
...
```

if i have the image in `/app/views/themed/my_theme/webroot/img/file.jpg` everything works 100%  but when i put the image in `/app/webroot/img/file.jpg` it will not show. i have tried all sorts of combinations for the

i have also tried using a plugin dir like `app/plugins/my_plugin/webroot/img/file.jpg` but the various paths ive tried will not show the image either.

any ideas how i can get the image to show? i dont mind if its for webroot/ or in plugins/xyz/, just as long as i can use the same image in many different themes with out having to duplicate the images

when the image is in /webroot/img i can use the full path like `url(http://locahost/my_app/img/file.jpg)` and it works.

**things that dont work**

url("img/file.jpg")

url("/img/file.jpg")

url("../img/file.jpg")

url("/../img/file.jpg")

url("../../img/file.jpg")

thanks.

Comment: steve and fahad19 had it right, ended up adding vhosts to my apache config so that there is no subfolders and then everything was good again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS file

`body{
     background-image: url('/img/file.jpg');
}`

This will use the root area to find the image in `/app/webroot/img/file.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

CSS has urls for images relative to the path it is placed in.

CSS files from my_theme are linked like site.com/theme/my_theme/css/style.css in the browser. So if you want to use an image from app/webroot/img in your theme's CSS, use url(../../../img/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that but the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1093/Themes) says:

> If you want to keep your theme assets
>   inside app/webroot it is recommended
>   that you rename app/webroot/themed to
>   app/webroot/theme.